Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Problem with old hardware
Can I run Kubuntu 22.04.4 Desktop on this old hardware?
The system boots OK, but selecting a menu within DISCOVERY causes the screen to freeze.
processor: Core-2 Quad Q8400 ram: 4GB video: NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT system: Kubuntu 22.4.4 LTS x86_64 6.5.0-45-generic kernel


Ubuntu 22.04 LTS offers multiple kernel stacks, with the default set by your install media. Kubuntu being a flavor of Ubuntu, follows the standard rules for Ubuntu flavor desktops; ie. GA & HWE default set by install media. For older hardware I find the GA kernel stack can be better; but you've not said what you actually used, as 22.04.4 using GA kernel is 5.15, but using HWE uses 6.5. Kubuntu 22.04 media was created using 5.15, 5.19, 6.2 & 6.5, with new media soon to have 6.8.  If you're booting Kubuntu 22.04.4 media you'll have 6.5 kernel & HWE stack

I used Kubuntu on my old 2006 Intel Dual Core2 system and only 1.5GB RAM. But with old slow hard drive when it went to swap it went black for a couple seconds. I learned to only load one larger app like Firefox & maybe a couple of smaller apps. But then I installed Kubuntu on external SSD and it made old system work well. swap was quick when it occurred, but still had to load only a few programs at once.

I'll give some more opinions based on my own QA that involves ~25 old boxes; the GPU really matters, and with newer kernels the desktops that show issues first are GNOME & KDE Plasma. First fix is as stated prior comment; use the older GA kernel stack option.. second work around is a lighter DE with Xfce last usually impacted; LXQt second last impacted... with others in between..   If you do want KDE Plasma, the kernel stack matters; so 5.15 is the oldest stack available for 22.04 LTS, 5.4 for 20.04 etc.
